# XPathNavigator.CheckValidity validates invalid XML document

Tags: .net, xml, .net-3.5, xsd, xml-validation

I'm trying to use [`XPathNavigator.CheckValidity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.checkvalidity.aspx) to validate an XML document.  Somehow, I was able to write tests that passed using this method, but now (mysteriously) aren't passing anymore.  The only thing that I can think of which changed was moving from .NET 2 to .NET 3.5, but I can't find any documentation on anything changing here during that transition.

Here's an example program:

```
void Main()
{
    try
    {
        GetManifest().CreateNavigator().CheckValidity(GetSchemaSet(), (sender, args) => {
            // never get in here when debugging
            if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error) {
                throw new XmlSchemaValidationException("Manifest failed validation", args.Exception);
            }
        }); // returns true when debugging
    }
    catch (XmlSchemaValidationException)
    {
        // never get here
        throw;
    }

    // code here runs
}

IXPathNavigable GetManifest()
{
    using (TextReader manifestReader = new StringReader("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?><BadManifest><bad>b</bad></BadManifest>"))
    {
        return new XPathDocument(manifestReader);
    }
}

XmlSchemaSet GetSchemaSet() 
{
    var schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
    using (var schemaReader = new StringReader(Schema)){
        schemaSet.Add(XmlSchema.Read(schemaReader, null));
    }

    return schemaSet;
}

const string Schema = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault=""unqualified"" elementFormDefault=""qualified"" xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" targetNamespace=""http://www.engagesoftware.com/Schemas/EngageManifest"">
  <xs:element name=""EngageManifest"">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name=""Title"" type=""xs:string"" />
        <xs:element name=""Description"" type=""xs:string"" />
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>";
```

I've tried the solution at [Validate XML with a XSD Schema without changing the XML using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780327/validate-xml-with-a-xsd-schema-without-changing-the-xml-using-c), but I'm getting the same result...  I must be missing some big consideration in how this validation thing works, but I can't see it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your XML is using the default namespace, but the XSD specifies a target namespace. If you specify `<BadManifest xmlns="http://www.engagesoftware.com/Schemas/EngageManifest">` in your XML, you should find that the validator reports errors as expected. Otherwise, since it doesn't recognise the namespace of the XML, it just ignores it.

Comment: So, is there a way to validate against the schema without requiring xmlns in the document?  Is it impossible to validate a document without an xmlns with an XSD that specifies a targetNamespace?

Comment: Basically they have to match - as far as XML is concerned, elements with the same name but different namespaces aren't related in any way. Your choices are either to leave out targetNamespace in the XSD or to set the namespace in the XML. You could set the namespace in the XML programmatically once you've parsed it, but if you need to do that then you need to think carefully about what purpose your namespace is fulfilling and why your input XML isn't in that namespace in the first place.

Comment: This is for user-supplied template documents, so requiring them to include the namespace seems too high a burden.  I'd wanted to have a namespace so that intellisense would be more automatic, but it looks like it's probably simplest to just remove the namespace, and they can manually associate with the XSD if they want intellisense.

Comment: Because we'd created templates both with and without the namespace specified, I've created a copy of our manifest which doesn't have the targetNamespace specified, and added both versions to the `XmlSchemaSet`.